# Change the size of a widget according to screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a fixed width widget . Is there a way to change the size of this widget according to screen size?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _mcq=["6",""];
</script>
<span id='_mc_mg6'></span>

<script language="JavaScript" src="http://stat1.moneycontrol.com/mcjs/common/mc_widget.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <a href="http://www.moneycontrol.com">Sensex/Nifty</a>
</noscript>
```

Is there any way to resize this widget according to screen size?

Comment: Where is you attempt to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: That's a flash widget... How are you expecting to make it responsive?

Comment: You can make it responsive if and only if you have access to its HTML/CSS/JS files

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the following code in the head:

```
<style>
@media(max-width: 500px) {
  /*..add css properties for classes that need to change here..*/
}
</style>
```

This will cause CSS defined in this object to be applied when screen size is less than 500px

Comment: the width of the widget is fixed . so the size of this widget doesn't change with screen size.

Comment: Can you show me your demo site if you have any. Even a brief explanation on jsfiddle may suffice.